# Writing a rqt plugin fails

Tags: ros, rqt-gui, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS users,

i tried to implement a C++ plugin (lets call it rqt_myplugin) following the tutorial rqt/Tutorials/Writing a C++ Plugin and the rqt_plugin ImageView. I am quite sure, that namespaces and classes are well defined in all  necessary files. The problem is, that when i am trying to execute my plugin by running

```
rosrun rqt_myplugin rqt_myplugin
```

i get the message:

```
qt_gui_main() found no plugin matching "rqt_myplugin"
```

Rqt doesn't show the plugin neither.

Could you explain, how rqt is aware of my created plugin? I thought that it should be enough to source devel/setup.bash.

I am using ROS Hydro and Kubuntu 12.10 32Bit.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/95386/writing-a-rqt-plugin-fails/) by [MZofka](https://answers.ros.org/users/8236/mzofka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-10-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-10-28**:
Did you add your plugin to your ROS path? I.e. what does `rospack find rqt_myplugin` return? Did you edit the plugin.xml file properly and doe the name match what your put in `rqt_myplugin`? Please provide us your current plugin.xml file.

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-10-29**:
Your plugin.xml seems ok. How is called your plug-in? (I mean the `.so` file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try out the suggestion of this answer: http://answers.ros.org/question/91231/rqt-plugin-not-listedfound-in-list-returned-by-rqt-list-plugins/?answer=91386#post-id-91386

This solved the issue for me.

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1